# Erro a usar date type no android

Tags: java, android, data

Eu tenho este código:

```
    String dt = "2017-01-04";  
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        sdf.parse(dt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Mas quando vou usar dt , num método que requer java.util.date , ele diz que não dt não esta correto porque é uma string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dt`é uma String. Foi declarado assim:

```
String dt = "2017-01-04";
```

O que você deve usar é o objecto Date retornado por:

```
sdf.parse(dt);
```

Algo assim:

```
String dt = "2017-01-04";  
Date data = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    data = sdf.parse(dt);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Passe a variável `data` ao método que requer java.util.date.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Só de salientar que precisei de fazer Date data=null;